# Git repository clone failed.missing CR

Tags: java, eclipse, git

Hi anybody can pls suggest any solution over this.i am trying to clone git repository but everytime i am getting the above message.this is the log which i am getting.

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: missing CR
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.CloneOperation.run(CloneOperation.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.AbstractGitCloneWizard.executeCloneOperation(AbstractGitCloneWizard.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.AbstractGitCloneWizard.access$2(AbstractGitCloneWizard.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.AbstractGitCloneWizard$5.run(AbstractGitCloneWizard.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: missing CR
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.doFetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp$SmartHttpFetchConnection.doFetch(TransportHttp.java:783)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.fetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.fetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.fetchObjects(FetchProcess.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1115)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:130)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: missing CR
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.processRaw(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAheadBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAhead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.io.UnionInputStream.read(UnionInputStream.java:145)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.io.TimeoutInputStream.read(TimeoutInputStream.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SideBandInputStream.read(SideBandInputStream.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.fill(PackParser.java:1131)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.access$000(PackParser.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser$InflaterStream.read(PackParser.java:1663)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.whole(PackParser.java:983)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.indexOneObject(PackParser.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.parse(PackParser.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.ObjectDirectoryPackParser.parse(ObjectDirectoryPackParser.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.parse(PackParser.java:448)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.receivePack(BasePackFetchConnection.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.doFetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:363)
    ... 15 more
```

please suggest any proper solution which will help me out.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

This seems be related to the autocrlf core option.

It may be in "input" option.

From [git core.autocrlf](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration):

- false: Do nothing in your commits
- true:  Convert all crlf to lf in your commit and viceversa in your checkouts.
- input: Convert all crlf to lf in your commit but leave lf in your checkouts.

You can find out the value of this parameter writting:

```
git config core.autocrlf
```

In your case, try to set the autocrlf to "true". This should change the lf of the repository to crlf in your working directory.

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

Comment: any another solution for this?

Comment: Change the value of autocrlf to "true".